# Detecting when image scrolls out of view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a div that will have a few images in it.  I would like for the images to disappear when the user scrolls to the point where the top or bottom edges of the image are just about to be hidden by the parent div.  The structure is like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <img/>
   <img/>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the image fade out when its top or bottom edges start to be hidden by the parent div, and then have it fade back in when its scrolled in to full view.

I am using jQuery and listening to the `div` scroll event to check the `img` `offset().top`, and once it hits a top value that is not in view, I hide the image.

But this seems to take up a lot of CPU time since I have to iterate through the images with each scroll event.  On top of that, even though I call `hide()` on the `img`, it doesn't hide it at all (put a break point in just to make sure it was getting called, and it was).  Is there an accurate way to do this?

**EDIT:**  Thanks to mcpDESIGNS, I was needed to use `position()` instead of `offset()`.  Also, it looks like `hide()` wont work since `display` is set to `none`.  So I switched to `visibility:hidden` and it works as expected.

**EDIT2:**  Just as a note, here is the js I am using, pretty much what mcpDesigns had suggested

*old*

```
var display = $("div");

display.scroll(function () {

    var avatars = $("div > img");
    console.log("************************");
    avatars.each(function (index) {
        console.log($(this).offset().top);

        if ($(this).offset().top < 40)
            $(this).hide();
        else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

*new*

```
var display = $("div");

display.scroll(function () {

    var avatars = $("div > img");
    console.log("************************");
    avatars.each(function (index) {
        console.log($(this).position().top);

        if ($(this).position().top < 0)
            $(this).css("visibility", "hidden")//.hide();
        else {
            $(this).css("visibility", "")//.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with a demo where the hide is not working?

Comment: Try to use `animate({opacity:0}, 1000)` instead of `hide()`. It doesn't change the `display` property.

Comment: thanks mark, wasnt really looking for a fade, but now that ive seen it, its staying in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to do a lot of calculations based on each image and whether it's position is either **negative** (meaning top of the parent scrollable div), or the same # as the **height of your scrollable div**.

```
​$('.parent').scroll(function () {            
    console.log($('img').position().top);

    // if ( negative top position || same#asDivheight) { fadeIn / out, etc }
});​
```

Play around with that, but that's basically the jist of it.

Comment: I started fiddling around with that, so there's no reason not to share it: http://jsfiddle.net/X6eCY/2/
It's not really fading in/out, the opacity is calculated based on the percentage of the image's visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a way you might find appropriate.

Code:

```
// initialize
var limit = 0;
var timeout;

var scrollCallback = function() {
    limit = 0;
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // TODO: calculations and hide/show images
}

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    limit++;
    if (limit > 50) {
        scrollCallback();
    }
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(scrollCallback, 500);
});​
```

This code will not fire the callback until you get 50 scroll events. Also, if 50 isn't reached, it will fire after 500 milliseconds. This might help you with the performance issue.

Comment: I thought of that, but only because i was thinking my selector of $(div > img) retrieved too many results.  Is there a way to get the img right at the top of the div?

Answer (score 0):

here is a little jsfiddle for your pleasure: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/35P2e/

```
$('.parent img').mousemove(function (e) {
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    if (y == $(this).position().top || y == $(this).height()-2)
    {
        alert($(this).position())
        $(this).hide();
    }else 
    {
        $(this).show();
    }
});​
```

-2 is the border height to catch true height of the element.. good luck..